# Expectation of a simple betting game

Tags: statistics

Probability of team A winning is 0.6, team B winning is 0.4

Betting rate for team A is 1.25, team B is 1.6 (ie. you'd get 1.25 times your initial bet if team A wins etc.)

What'd you expect to get from this game?

So far I tried $\omega=\{(A,win),(A,lost),(B,win),(B,lost)\}$

$X:\Omega\to R$ with $X(A,win)=1.25$, $X(A,lose)=0$, $X(B,win)=1.6$, $X(B,lose)=0$

So the expected value would be $E(X)=1.25*0.3+0*0.2+1.6*0.2+0*0.3=0.695$

Which means you'd lose 30% of your bet if you participated in this game. Is that correct?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  How much are you betting on each team?

Comment: @lulu Good question.  Reverse engineering, the OP's (i.e. original poster's) analysis is valid if and only if it is assumed that the bettor is wagering exactly $(1/2)$ unit on each of the two teams.

Comment: $0.6 \times 1.25=0.75$ so you expect to lose $25\%$ of any bet on A.  $0.4 \times 1.6=0.64$ so you expect you to $36\%$ of any bet on B.  You seem to have taken the average of these